# Trying to get CLLocation coordinates before loading WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, wkwebview

Basically based on the coordinates, I get the state (NY,CA etc) and based on the state, I access a specific url which I use WKWebView()  to open the website.

However, I keep getting nil for the url by the time webView needs to load it.
If I comment out the `webView.load(URLRequest(url: url!)))`, I noticed that url value isn't nil (via a print statement). So basically, I need to get the coordinate value before webView is ready to load a url.
I've played around with the ordering but I can't get it to work.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import CoreLocation


class ViewController: UIViewController,  WKNavigationDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var state: String?

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let translator = CLGeocoder()
    var webView: WKWebView!


    var locationsDict : [String:String] = ["CA" : "https://stackoverflow.com",
                                           "NY": "https://old.reddit.com"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer // You can change the locaiton accuary here.
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }



            webView = WKWebView()
            webView.navigationDelegate = self
            view = webView



            var url: URL?
            if state != nil{
                    let urlString = locationsDict[state!]
                    print(urlString)
                        if urlString != nil{
                                url = URL(string: urlString!)!

                }
                }
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
        //webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
            print(state)

        }


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.first {

            translator.reverseGeocodeLocation(location){(placemark, error) in
                if error != nil{
                    print("There was an error")
                }
                else{
                    if let place = placemark?[0]
                    {
                        if let temp = place.administrativeArea{
                                self.state = temp
                            print(self.state!)
                    }

                        else {print ("Cant find location")}
                }
            }





        }
    }
    }

    // If we have been deined access give the user the option to change it
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if(status == CLAuthorizationStatus.denied) {
            showLocationDisabledPopUp()
        }
    }




    // Show the popup to the user if we have been deined access
    func showLocationDisabledPopUp() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Background Location Access Disabled",
                                                message: "In order to deliver pizza we need your location",
                                                preferredStyle: .alert)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        let openAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Open Settings", style: .default) { (action) in
            if let url = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            }
        }
        alertController.addAction(openAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

I'm at a loss :(   Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where are you actually setting `state`? In a delegate method? If so, that delegate method probably isn't getting triggered in time (i.e., location updates don't start fast enough to "beat" your `viewDidLoad` method).

Comment: @aaplmath Okay, updated OP. It's within the delegate method.

Comment: @aaplmath can you please load url in didUpdateLocations and make sure to check can you get coordinate or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than launching the `WKWebView` right after requesting permission, it'd be better to do it once you actually have a location (ie. in the delegate)

`func locationManager(CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations: [CLLocation])` would be an ideal place to do it, just make sure to only perform your action once as this delegate method would be continuously called. 
Alternatively, you could also do it in the `didChangeAuthorization` function.

Comment: Another option would be to use `CLLocationManager.requestLocation()`, which only performs one location update, rather than `startUpdatingLocation()`.